# Mouse stuck after updating 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mouse

I applied a large number of updates to Ubuntu 12.04 (if someone would tell me how to get a list of the applied patches, and I would be happy to post it here), and my mouse refuses to move.

How can I fix this issue, or at least revert the updates so that my functionality is restored?

**Note:** Ubuntu is running under Hyper-V on a Win 8 Host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that somehow, some of the updates were corrupted, and did not complete (or similar, not really sure what happened, or why).

To fix, run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

And then restart.